# gitlab-ci schedule job cron every minute

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

New way for 12.8.X

To change the Sidekiq worker’s frequency:
Edit the **gitlab_rails['pipeline_schedule_worker_cron']** value in your instance’s **gitlab.rb** file.
The exact line I have checked from gitlab.rb file is

```
# gitlab_rails['pipeline_schedule_worker_cron'] = "19 * * * *"
```

Reconfigure GitLab for the changes to take effect.

Older version 10.x.x the good way is.
Edit the **gitlab_ci['schedule_builds_minute'] = "0"** value in your instance’s **gitlab.rb** file.

Please check the the official page, it's changing offen
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html#advanced-configuration

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

To change the Sidekiq worker’s frequency:

Edit the **gitlab_rails['pipeline_schedule_worker_cron']** value in your instance’s **gitlab.rb** file.
Reconfigure GitLab for the changes to take effect.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html#advanced-configuration